# How do I tell if a row exists in a table?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

For example:

```
select name from person where id=2;
```

I wand to know if this row exists, and depending on its existence perform a certain task.
I wan to do this using jdbc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to invoke this select query,

After the successful execution of query you would have instance of [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) returned, you could check by invoking [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) if it returns true it means there was a row selected

```
if(resultSet.next()){
   //yes exist
}
```

Comment: Not said here, but generally understood is that your prepared statement would change slightly: PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select name from person where id=?"); pstmt.setInt(1,2);

Answer (score 4):

```
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url , databaseUserName, databasePassword);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = null;           
            result = stmt.executeQuery("select name from person where id=2;");
            if(!result.isBeforeFirst()){
                System.out.println("No Data Found"); //data not exist
            }
           else{
              // data exist
              }
```

isBeforeFirst() returns true if the cursor is before the first row; false if the cursor is at any other position or the result set contains no rows

Comment: `result.isBeforeFirst()` gives the best results!

Answer (score 4):

The is no **hasNext()** method in **ResultSet**. The **next()** method moves the cursor to the next row and if there is a row then it returns true.

```
if(resultSet.next()){
  //do something

}
else{
  //no next row found

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use JdbcTemplate.queryForList which [returns an empty list if there are no rows.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-)

```
db.queryForList(sql, params).isEmpty();
```